# Methods and return problems

Tags: java, methods, area

Anyone knows what this error means:

```
RectangleArea.java:21: error: method getLength in class RectangleArea cannot be applied to given types;


  length = getLength();
            ^
  required: double,Scanner

  found: no arguments

  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length 

     import java.util.Scanner;

     public class RectangleArea
     {
       public static void main (String [] args)
       {
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
         double length,    // The rectangle's length
         width,     // The rectangle's width\
         area;      // The rectangle's area
         welcomeBanner ();
         // Get the rectangle's length from the user.
         length = getLength();
      }
      static void getLength(double aLength, Scanner aKeyboard)
      {
        System.out.print("Enter the rectangle's length: ");
        aLength = aKeyboard.nextDouble ();
        System.out.println("");
        return aLength;
      }
    }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well look at the parameters of `getLength`... then look at the arguments you're passing (none)...

Comment: can you explain the arguments stuff? i'm kinda lost there

Comment: What's the purpose of `getLength(...)`? It returns a value that you are asked to input.

Comment: If you're confused about how to call methods, I'd strongly recommend reading a good book or tutorial. Stack Overflow is great for specific problems when you've got the basics of a language, but it's not a good way to *start* learning a language.

Comment: I formatted the code the best I could. It seems like there is an error and then there is a separate block of code, but I'm not sure where the split is.

Answer (score 0):

`getLength` is a void method. If you want to return something you need to replace `void` with a data type, `double` in your case. You also need to make sure you are passing correct parameters types and the correct number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The method `getLength()`:

1. It takes 2 parameters `double aLength` and `Scanner aKeyboard`.
2. You are assigning this value to length which is a `double`, but you are returning nothing (`void`) from the method `getLength()`.

What if you try this:

```
static double getLength()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    double aLength;
    System.out.print("Enter the rectangle's length: ");
    length = keyboard.nextDouble ();
    System.out.println("");
    return length;
}
```

In addition you should remove the variable `keyboard` from your `main()` method.